# Big $O$ notation and Little $o$ notation

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Assume that $A_{n}=O_{p}(n^{-1/2})$ is true.

Is the following statement true or false?

$A_{n}=O_{p}(n^{-1/2})  =o_{p}(1) $

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$, I believe that the statement is accurate.

Comment: What is you definition of little-o?

Comment: Or more pedantically, $A_n\in O(n^{-1/2})\subseteq o(1)\implies A_n\in o(1)$.

Comment: Also tell us what is $O_p$.  And tell us $n \to \infty$, if that is what you want.

Comment: @Gary. I dk whether you want to know the definition of the Landau little-oh or whether you are telling the proposer to use the def'n.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I know very well what little-o means. I would like to know which definition does the OP use.